# Is it possible to get in a var (javascript) the value of a clicked bar in Chart?

Tags: charts

Is it possible to get the value of a var (javascript) clicked in Chart?
I need to get the value and put it into a var in javascript when someone click in the bar.

Here is my code:

```
const $grafica = document.querySelector("#grafica");
const mesos = ["Ene.", "Feb.", "Mar.", "Apr.", "May.", "Jun.", "Jul.", "Aug.", "Sep.", "Oct.", "Nov.", "Dic."]
const horesAny2023 = {
    label: "Year 2023",
    data: [52,48,53,55,54,55,51,32,55,55,52,51],
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(4,107,186,0.2)',
    borderColor: 'rgba(54,162,235,1)',
    borderWidth: 2,
};
new Chart($grafica, {
    type: 'bar',// Tipo de gráfica
    data: {
        labels: mesos,
        datasets: [ horesAny2023 ]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                 ticks: { beginAtZero: true }
            }],
        },
    }
});
```